# ExecuteScalar() always return NULL

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql, executescalar

I am trying to return an integer from the database using ExecuteScalar(). However, when I run the query on the database itself, I get the correct answer, and c# gives me a 0 (Null) all the time. I know it returns a null because before i added `id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());` it would give me an error telling me to make sure NULL is handled. I am expecting it to return a 3 btw.

```
 private int getFamilyId()
 {
    int id = 0;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Globaldata.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            string sqlString = @"SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[FamilyDetails];";
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = sqlString;
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is what I get when I run it on the database]

Comment: Check the connection string. Do it point to the same database you're executing the query against ?

Comment: What if you remove ; in the query text?

Comment: Yes, Its the correct database because I copied the connection string from database->properties->connectionstring.

Comment: I removed ; its the same result.

Comment: @AlbinVinoy Debug the code you're shown and check the object `connection` and check the `ConnectionString` property.

Comment: use this line `command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` before it enters the `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
string sqlString = @"SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[FamilyDetails];";
```

You don't want to do this:

```
id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Three things could go wrong here.

- Problem #1:
  If there are no rows in the table, command.ExecuteScalar() wil return **Null**.
- Problem #2:
  If there are any rows in the table, command.ExecuteScalar() wil return the value of the first rows it happens to encounter because the SELECT statement is not restricted to 1 value.
- Problem #3:
  If the Id column is not declared as **NOT NULL** command.ExecuteScalar() could return a **DbNull**, which which makes no sense when converted to an Integer.

Try and see what happens when there are 0 or 1 or 2 records in the table.

Comment: How do you suggest that I change that line of code?

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without the create table statement and why you need the value of the ID.

The bottom line is that ExecuteScalar returns only one value, while the SELECT statement can return no value at all or even a long list of values.

Answer (score 1):

--UPDATE--

It works now, My connection string had one character missing. I think it happened when I took out the connection Timeout part of the connection string.

Thank you for your suggestions!!!

Comment: what was your connection string before and later when it got fixed. please mention them as well.

Comment: It was just a typo, I accidentally deleted the e from True 
Original Connection : `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Users\RecordDatabaseFile.mdf;Integrated Security=Tru;Connect Timeout=10`
Changed it to: `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Users\RecordDatabaseFile.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=10`